# How to run existing JAVA Web start application in java 10 or later java 11

Tags: java, java-web-start

My application is developed in java Swings which is 20 years old. For this huge application we are migrating the same on JAVA 10 now and will migrate the same on java 11 or upcoming versions. This application is working fine with java Webstart and as per the java 11 features, java Web Start application will not be supported in java 11 and other coming versions.

Please let me know the best way to run my application on java 10 with out webstart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [OpenWebStart](https://openwebstart.com/) start project. It says:

> we decided to create OpenWebStart, an open source reimplementation of
>   the Java Web Start technology. Our replacement will provide the most
>   commonly used features of Java Web Start and the JNLP standard, so
>   that your customers can continue using applications based on Java Web
>   Start and JNLP without any change.

At the moment the project is alpha phase. [Download](https://openwebstart.com/download/) is available. Beta should be available by the end of the year:

> Our goal is to have beta tests and a release candidate ready in
>   Q3/2019

Comment: Beta download is available now

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be the WebStart replacement that Karakun is currently working on: https://dev.karakun.com/webstart/

Currently it is not clear when and how this will come since it is based on a kind of crowd-founding but since everyone can get involved (even with low cost) this is a very good possibility.

Since this is a duplicate of [Applet/JNLP on Java 11 migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981336/applet-jnlp-on-java-11-migration/52381741#52381741) I just copied my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use Getdown which is a system for deploying Java applications to end-user computers, as well as keeping those applications up to date.

It was designed as a replacement for Java Web Start due to limitations in Java Web Start's.

You can read more on https://github.com/threerings/getdown

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find an alternative technology to JWS/JNLP to run your system, as JWS/JNLP will no longer be available.

I don't have a clear cut alternative, the few companies still using JWS tend to be working to develop their own replacements for internal use.

I know this may not be what you want to hear (that there is no out of the box replacement available) but that's the way it is. Project I'm working on is in a similar conundrum, we also have several JWS components that will need to be reworked in the near future.