# Applet/JNLP on Java 11 migration

Tags: java, jnlp, japplet

I have an application that runs under Java/JNLP applet and I would like to migrate to Java 11.

As you know the applets and JNLP will disappear from Java 11.

The goal is to keep my old code and remove the packages that contain the applets, is it possible to do this migration without switching to a new technology?

Comment: *"is it possible to do this migration without switching to a new technology?"* No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I chose Swing with Getdown which resembles JNLP.

A migration to a JEE/Spring solution would have completely modified the operation of my application and still take a lot of time. Tip: try it for yourself [Getdown](http://github.com/threerings/getdown).

Comment: That is why I mentioned that it depends on your type of appliation. Compare my remark (2). And if getdown helps you in keeping your app up-to-date then perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Yes and No.

**Yes** you can keep your java business logic and data handling code (presumed you did a clean separation of your application layers). E.g. just convert to a standalone java app and you're fine.

**No**, if you look for something to run in the webbrowser then you have to migrate to JavaScript/HTML/JSF/GWT... on the frontend and your java code running on the backend (JEE or Servlets ...).

Regarding the "No", it depends on what kind of application you have. A web application or a standalone application?

(1) For a web application you have to recreate the front end part (UI, communication with the server) but you can reuse parts of your logic.

(2) For a standalone application (using Swing/AWT/JavaFX ...) you can keep your code, just create a standalone app out of it. For distribution e.g. JavaFX offers an [application packaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm) mechanism.

PS: The quickest way could be the conversion to the webstart technology however it was also deprecated and will be also be removed in future. So I would **not** use it.

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be the WebStart replacement that Karakun is currently working on: https://dev.karakun.com/webstart/

Currently it is not clear when and how this will come since it is based on a kind of crowd-founding but since everyone can get involved (even with low cost) this is a very good possibility.

Comment: Ah didn't know - interesting project!

Comment: Page moved to https://openwebstart.com/ and there are some alpha versions published already.