# Prevent Java Application from performing malicious activities

Tags: java, security, java-security, java-security-manager

I need to download and run a Jar file. Is there a way to know what it can/will do? I mean what permissions it has? Specifically I need to know if it will try to access my files and if it will try to use my internet. When I download an android application, I can clearly see what permissions it seeks. Is there something similar for Java desktop apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, it does: Java Web Start (which is now removed from Java 11) was enforcing permissions using *security policy* (which is still available).

These checks still exists and are thoroughly explained here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html

They are probably rarely used on a desktop app without Java Web Start, but you can always give a try.

Comment: Why was it removed from Java 11? What are the alternatives now?

Comment: @ScienceGuy: https://www.oracle.com/.../java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf blames app stores, which seems weak to me. (Blaming browsers for removing applet/plugin made more sense; that does depend on browser support.) See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904795/java-web-start-support-in-java-9-and-beyond https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981336/applet-jnlp-on-java-11-migration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55930547/openjdk-and-java-webstart . But note removal of 'deployment' (applet/plugin and webstart/JNLP) does NOT mean removal of SecurityManager.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Your answer is just one last step away from helpful. Can you share a resouece where I can see how I can use the SecurityManager to grant limited permissions to the Jar file lying on my Dekstop?

Comment: Granted. I added "which is still available".